# Cabal doesn't find the correct package

Tags: haskell, cabal

```
⇒ cabal build           
./vinyltest.cabal has been changed. Re-configuring with most recently used
options. If this fails, please run configure manually.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring vinyltest-0.1.0.0...
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
filePath -any
```

--

```
⇒ cabal install filePath
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
filepath-1.3.0.1
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway
```

How can this happen? It tells me that filePath is missing and if I try to install it, it tells me that it is already installed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried re-running `cabal configure` manually? Also, note that `filePath` and `filepath` are not the same (despite `cabal install` working with both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that this is a typo in your build-depends restriction in `vinyltest.cabal`. You have `filePath`, while the actual package name is `filepath` (lower case 'p'). `cabal install` does not particularly care, but `ghc-pkg` (which is used by cabal configure/build) is case sensitive.

```
$ ghc-pkg list filepath
/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.6.3/package.conf.d
   filepath-1.3.0.1
/home/elliot/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d

$ ghc-pkg list filePath
/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.6.3/package.conf.d
/home/elliot/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d
```

Note how the capitalized 'P' does not find the package, while the correctly-capitalized lower-case 'p' does.